# Was: Not unique table :: Now: #1054 - Unknown column - can't understand why?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1054, mysql-error-1066

I'm trying to join some tables together in MySQL, but I seem to get an error saying: #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'calendar_jobs'

I really want it to select everything from the cal_events, the 2 user bits and just the destination col from the jobs table, but become "null" if there arn't any job. A right join seemed to fit the bill but doesn't work! Can anyone help!?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for the help on the previous query, I'm now up to this:

```
SELECT calendar_events.* , calendar_users.doctorOrNurse, calendar_users.passportName, calendar_jobs.destination
FROM `calendar_events` , `calendar_users`
RIGHT JOIN calendar_jobs ON calendar_events.jobID = calendar_jobs.jobID
WHERE `start` >= 0
AND calendar_users.userID = calendar_events.userID;
```

But am now getting an error saying: #1054 - Unknown column 'calendar_events.jobID' in 'on clause'

What is it this time!?

Thanks again!

Comment: No duplicates please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021587/1054-unknown-column-sql-query-problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `calendar_jobs` in the FROM clause, because you've already specified it in the JOIN. Try this:

```
SELECT calendar_events.* , calendar_users.doctorOrNurse, calendar_users.passportName, calendar_jobs.destination
FROM `calendar_events` , `calendar_users`
RIGHT JOIN calendar_jobs ON calendar_events.jobID = calendar_jobs.jobID
WHERE `start` >=0
AND calendar_users.userID = calendar_events.userID
```

---

Answer for update:

All evidence seems to indicate that the column doesn't exist in that table :).

Try this:

```
SELECT calendar_events.* , calendar_users.doctorOrNurse, calendar_users.passportName, calendar_jobs.destination
FROM `calendar_users`, `calendar_events`
RIGHT JOIN calendar_jobs ON calendar_events.jobID = calendar_jobs.jobID
WHERE `start` >=0
AND calendar_users.userID = calendar_events.userID
```

The order of the tables in the FROM has been switched, because you join events with jobs.

Comment: It's defiantly there! I can see it from here, even copies and pasted to be sure... Is it because of the "where" statement below?

Answer (score 1):

Run this: `show create table calendar_events;` , and post the results here.

We need to see the table structure to answer your second question.

Answer (score 0):

You have `calendar_jobs` listed twice in your query.

Once on the second line and once on the RIGHT JOIN statement.

Comment: AhhH! Thanks for that... however, i'm now getting:  Unknown column 'calendar_events.jobID' in 'on clause'

Whats that all about!? It's defiantly there!

Comment: Why don't you run `mysql > DESC calendar_events; ` to double check that the column is actually there.

Comment: Hiya, done that... all seems fine to me! Its certainly there!