# #1054 - Unknown column - SQL Query Problem

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1054

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Was: Not unique table :: Now: #1054 - Unknown column - can't understand why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021429/was-not-unique-table-now-1054-unknown-column-cant-understand-why)

After having solved a previous issue with this query, i'm now stuck with getting this error:

> 1054 - Unknown column 'calendar_events.jobID ' in 'on clause'

I can't undertstand why... and the column defiantly exists! Is it something to do with the WHERE blah AND ... section of the query at the bottom?

```
SELECT calendar_events.* , 
       calendar_users.doctorOrNurse, 
       calendar_users.passportName, 
       calendar_jobs.destination
  FROM `calendar_users` , `calendar_events`
INNER JOIN `calendar_jobs` ON `calendar_events.jobID` = `calendar_jobs.jobID`
     WHERE `start` >=0
       AND calendar_users.userID = calendar_events.userID
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: You have now asked this question twice as you have asked within this question too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021429/was-not-unique-table-now-1054-unknown-column-cant-understand-why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
You should use `calendar_events`.`jobID` instead of `calendar_events.jobID`.
```

Answer (score 1):

> INNER JOIN and , (comma) are
>   semantically equivalent in the absence
>   of a join condition: both produce a
>   Cartesian product between the
>   specified tables (that is, each and
>   every row in the first table is joined
>   to each and every row in the second
>   table).
>
> However, the precedence of the comma
>   operator is less than of INNER JOIN,
>   CROSS JOIN, LEFT JOIN, and so on. If
>   you mix comma joins with the other
>   join types when there is a join
>   condition, an error of the form
>   Unknown column 'col_name' in 'on
>   clause' may occur. Information about
>   dealing with this problem is given
>   later in this section.

From:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Hope this helps